ARRAYFORMULA doesn't work with entire column reference
I am trying to build a sheet that will return a date base on when a stock price passed a specific price level for the first time (called and order triggered in stock trading).
Column A for date - Data from CVS
Column B for Price - Data from CVS
Column C for Checking if price is above the price level - My formula
$J$4 For desired price - My data
The way I was trying to achieve that is by creating several formulas that check if the price at the date was above the desired price level:
IF(B:B>$J$4,1,-1)
the reason there is an entire column reference (B:B) is because i want a singe cell that will tell me the date so i prepared the formulas in such way that they will fit in an array.
Next, I create a formula that show me the date if the price is above desired price: If price is lower then desired price, formula returns blank for that date:
IF(C:C=1,A:A,"")
And finally, I combined them together:
IF(IF(B:B>$K$4,1,-1)=1,A:A,"") --- I no longer need formulas in column C
Now I want to create an array out of this formula so a MIN function could find the first date the desired price was hit:
ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IF(B:B>$K$4,1,-1)=1,A:A,"")))
^^^
This results in an #REF error:
Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more rows (4).
Where am I wrong?
I want the formula to just return an array of dates, Don't want to use additional columns to get the result I want.
